# When normalising, if you have entities with the same primary key, does it mean it should be the same entity?

Tags: database-design, normalization

Crrently I have this check in data where each check in has check-in details, activities and total extra items charge(extra items are required for some activities).

In UNF, I separated them into 3 repeating groups:

**CHECKIN**( (customer_id, customer_name, check_in_d&t, main_tour_guide),

(activity_code, activity_name, prescribing_tour_guide, completing_tour_guide, activity_d&t,activity_cost),

(item_code, description, quantity, total_item_charge, quantity, **total_extra_item_charges**))

If I group total_extra_item_charges under item, I will get 3NF:

**TOTALITEMCHARGES**( **customer_id, activity_d&t**, total_extra_item_charges)

**ACTIVITYSCHEDULE**( **customer_id, activity_d&t** , activity_code, prescribing_tour_guide, completing_tour_guide)

Both of these share the same primary key, so should I group total_extra_item_charges under activity schedule instead since 1 activity only has 1 total extra charge?But something seems off?

*d&t means date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `total_extra_item_charges` into the same table as the activities. You are unnecessarily duplicating `customer_id` and `activity_d&t` for a single column that you indicate will not have more than one row. Try to avoid *over*-normalizing.

I would also recommend a primary key on a unique identity column (e.g. `activity_schedule_id`). Based on your bolding of `customer_id` and `activity_d&t`, it appears you're using a composite primary key. A datetime column is not typically suitable as a primary key and is going to add significant physical overhead. I would instead add a nonclustered index and foreign key on `customer_id` with an include on `activity_d&t`.

Depending on the transactional volume of this database, you may also want to split the date and time portions of `activity_d&t` for quicker join lookups. E.g. `activity_date` and `activity_time`. Be mindful of the precision level you use for your `time` - do you need seconds and milliseconds? If you just need to be precise to the minute, be sure you aren't storing this data as you can save a significant amount of space.